# Add px.scatterplot to px.imshow?

Tags: python, plotly, data-visualization, visualization

I've been having a lot of problems with something I've been trying to do. The idea is to replicate a common excel heatmap(thats how they call it) in python with **plotly graphs**!. The heatmap should look like this:

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0FjV.png]

What I got so far(thanks to an answer provided from this forum) is:

```
import plotly.express as px
data = [[1, 1, 2, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 3, 4], [2, 3, 3, 4, 5], [2, 3, 4, 5, 5], [3, 4, 5, 5, 5]]

fig = px.imshow(data, color_continuous_scale=["darkgreen", "lightgreen", "yellow", "orange", "red"])

fig.update_yaxes(autorange=True)
fig.update_layout(
    xaxis=dict(
        tickmode='linear',
        tick0=1,
        dtick=1
    ),
    autosize=False,
    width=500
)
# fig.layout['coloraxis']['colorbar']['x'] = 1.0
fig.update_layout(coloraxis_colorbar=dict(
    tickvals=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    ticktext=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    x=1.0
))
fig.show()
```

Which gives us the following graph:

[image]

Now I have the **sample** of the scatterplot that looks like

```
import plotly.express as px
fig = px.scatter(x=[3.8,4.4,4.1,3.7,4.2],y=[4.9,3.9,2.5,3.6,2.1])
fig.update_xaxes(
    range=[0, 5])
fig.update_yaxes(
    range=[0, 5])
fig.show()
```

[image]
So the only thing thats left is to add the trace of a scatterplot from the plotly.express library. BUT it seems that imshow and scatterplots are not compatible. So I have no idea how to make this work.

Any help would be really really appreciated!

Thanks so much!

Comment: First things first, there is an indentation error in all of the functions/code you had provided. Please try to [edit] it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your heatmap is a little bit off, but using the `graph_objects` library from plotly and creating a subplot using `go.Scatter`, I was able to add the scatter points to the code that you provided for the heatmap:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[3.8,4.4,4.1,3.7,4.2],y=[4.9,3.9,2.5,3.6,2.1], mode='markers', marker=dict(color=['black'])))
```

Adding this gave an output that looked like this:
[image]

The full code looks like this:

```
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go

data = [[1, 1, 2, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 3, 4], [2, 3, 3, 4, 5], [2, 3, 4, 5, 5], [3, 4, 5, 5, 5]]

fig = px.imshow(data, color_continuous_scale=["darkgreen", "lightgreen", "yellow", "orange", "red"])

fig.update_yaxes(autorange=True)
fig.update_layout(
    xaxis=dict(
        tickmode='linear',
        tick0=1,
        dtick=1
    ),
    autosize=False,
    width=500
)
# fig.layout['coloraxis']['colorbar']['x'] = 1.0
fig.update_layout(coloraxis_colorbar=dict(
    tickvals=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    ticktext=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    x=1.0
))

import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[3.8,4.4,4.1,3.7,4.2],y=[4.9,3.9,2.5,3.6,2.1], mode='markers', marker=dict(color=['black'])))

fig.show()
```

Comment: First of all, thanks so much for your answer and second, do you know a way to make both plots fit? Thanks so much again <3

Comment: The workaround that I figured out was subtracting one from each x and y value for the scatter plot. The data changes to this: `x=[2.7,3.3,3.0,2.6,3.1],y=[3.8,2.8,1.4,2.5,1.0]`